# Regex for new line not working in textarea jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, textarea

I am trying to convert returned output copied from router that consist of multiple `\r\n` to new line to be as pretty result configuration with indention for user viewing from UI. However my script below is not working. I have refer some reference from googling also not help much. Anyone have solution? Currently I am develop using MacOS platform and latest Chrome.

example output

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "output": {
    "ipv4_address": "xxx/xx",
  },
  "ne_response": "... \r\r\n--- {master}\r\nRouter@xyz> show ... inet address xxx/30\r\n\r\n{master}\r\nRouter@xyz> "
}
```

current output (`\r\n` not working)

[image]

html

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="viewConfig"></textarea>
```

jQuery (all not convert to new line)

```
 $("#viewConfig").on("keyup", function(){
    var vConfig = $("#viewConfig").val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "\\n"); // double backslash not working
    var vConfig = $("#viewConfig").val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "\n"); // single backslash not working
    $('#viewConfig').html(vConfig);
});

$("#viewConfig").on("keyup", function(){
    var vConfig = $('#viewConfig').val().replace(/\n/g, "\\n"); // double backslash not working
    var vConfig = $('#viewConfig').val().replace(/\n/g, "\n"); // single backslash not working
    $('#viewConfig').html(vConfig);
});

$("#viewConfig").on("keyup", function(){
    var vConfig = $("#viewConfig").val().replace(/[\r\n]+/gm, "&#13;&#10;");
    $('#viewConfig').html(vConfig);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you actually want to do is replace multiple occurrences of `\r` or `\n` with a single `\n`. You can do that with the regex `[\r\n]+`, which will match one or more `\r` or `\n` characters. You can then replace that with a single newline `"\n"`. Note that you need to replace the `val`, not the `html` when referring to a textarea.

Type a character in the textbox below to see the effect:

```js
$("#viewConfig").val("... \r\r\n--- {master}\r\nRouter@xyz> show ... inet address xxx/30\r\n\r\n{master}\r\nRouter@xyz> ")

$("#viewConfig").on("keyup", function(){
    var vConfig = $(this).val().replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "\n");
    $(this).val(vConfig);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="viewConfig" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Note you can simply use `$(this)` to refer to `$("#viewConfig")` in the event handler (see the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).

Comment: Hi, I have problem, I tried to not use the pre-defined value as your answer above in the textarea and I try to paste the router same configuration in the textarea. but the regex is not working. why?

Comment: @mastersuse are you sure they are actual newlines? If you paste text into the snippet text area it works as expected

Comment: yes, in router it is newline. the flow is like this, API will get the configuration from router and become `\r\n`. Then I will copy and paste the configuration in the `<textarea>` but the `\r\n` is not function. the result is like my posting earlier. long string.

Comment: @mastersuse well if the characters are going in to the textarea as `\r` and `\n` (i.e. backslash followed by r or n), you'd need to modify the regex to match that instead e.g. `/(?:\\[rn])+/g`